# Why does the content overflow when mu content is set to 100% height

Tags: html, css

My layout has a header and footer and in between those a content div.

When I set my content height to 100% it overflows instead of expanding the div.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.header,
.footer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Heading</h1>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>Sapibulumnibh phasellus nulla egestibulum enim pretium elit tincidunt estiquam ultrisque donectetur. Sedcondimentumsan odio hendrerit proin vitae dignis nibh ac justo id congue. Amesintesque vel curabitae volutpat donec alique nasceleifendimentesque
    montesque rhoncus quis eros. Vestnunc nonummy</p>

  <span>
                Sapibulumnibh phasellus nulla egestibulum enim pretium elit tincidunt estiquam ultrisque donectetur. Sedcondimentumsan odio hendrerit proin vitae dignis nibh ac justo id congue. Amesintesque vel curabitae volutpat donec alique nasceleifendimentesque montesque rhoncus quis eros. Vestnunc nonummy
            </span>
  <p>Sapibulumnibh phasellus nulla egestibulum enim pretium elit tincidunt estiquam ultrisque donectetur. Sedcondimentumsan odio hendrerit proin vitae dignis nibh ac justo id congue. Amesintesque vel curabitae volutpat donec alique nasceleifendimentesque
    montesque rhoncus quis eros. Vestnunc nonummy</p>

  <span>
                Sapibulumnibh phasellus nulla egestibulum enim pretium elit tincidunt estiquam ultrisque donectetur. Sedcondimentumsan odio hendrerit proin vitae dignis nibh ac justo id congue. Amesintesque vel curabitae volutpat donec alique nasceleifendimentesque montesque rhoncus quis eros. Vestnunc nonummy
            </span>
  <p>Sapibulumnibh phasellus nulla egestibulum enim pretium elit tincidunt estiquam ultrisque donectetur. Sedcondimentumsan odio hendrerit proin vitae dignis nibh ac justo id congue. Amesintesque vel curabitae volutpat donec alique nasceleifendimentesque
    montesque rhoncus quis eros. Vestnunc nonummy</p>

  <span>
                Sapibulumnibh phasellus nulla egestibulum enim pretium elit tincidunt estiquam ultrisque donectetur. Sedcondimentumsan odio hendrerit proin vitae dignis nibh ac justo id congue. Amesintesque vel curabitae volutpat donec alique nasceleifendimentesque montesque rhoncus quis eros. Vestnunc nonummy
            </span>
  <p>Sapibulumnibh phasellus nulla egestibulum enim pretium elit tincidunt estiquam ultrisque donectetur. Sedcondimentumsan odio hendrerit proin vitae dignis nibh ac justo id congue. Amesintesque vel curabitae volutpat donec alique nasceleifendimentesque
    montesque rhoncus quis eros. Vestnunc nonummy</p>

  <span>
                Sapibulumnibh phasellus nulla egestibulum enim pretium elit tincidunt estiquam ultrisque donectetur. Sedcondimentumsan odio hendrerit proin vitae dignis nibh ac justo id congue. Amesintesque vel curabitae volutpat donec alique nasceleifendimentesque montesque rhoncus quis eros. Vestnunc nonummy
            </span>
  <p>Sapibulumnibh phasellus nulla egestibulum enim pretium elit tincidunt estiquam ultrisque donectetur. Sedcondimentumsan odio hendrerit proin vitae dignis nibh ac justo id congue. Amesintesque vel curabitae volutpat donec alique nasceleifendimentesque
    montesque rhoncus quis eros. Vestnunc nonummy</p>

  <span>
                Sapibulumnibh phasellus nulla egestibulum enim pretium elit tincidunt estiquam ultrisque donectetur. Sedcondimentumsan odio hendrerit proin vitae dignis nibh ac justo id congue. Amesintesque vel curabitae volutpat donec alique nasceleifendimentesque montesque rhoncus quis eros. Vestnunc nonummy
            </span>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <h1>Footer
    <h1>
</div>
```

I already know the solution is to get rid of the 100% height. 
**But what I want to know is why does this happen.** Shouldn't 100% height expand it's height to fit the parent?

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8wdh32ak/) for my code.

Comment: change height to `min-height`

Comment: No, because your initial setting makes the body 100% of the **screen**. Try using `min-height:100%` instead.

Comment: Or set height:auto for the content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it will overflow.

What height : 100% does is to take the parent's height and use it as its height. It doesn't take what's left of the height remaining, instead it takes the original height of the parent and set it as it's height. I think that's the explanation you want.

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't 100% height expand it's height to fit the parent?

Yes, but the overflow comes because you have set a fixed height for the parent, so it can't grow.

I recommend you to not use `height: 100%` for the main containers like `html` and `body`, because you will want it to be flexible. You also will want for these containers to be at least the initial screen height, so use this:

```
html,
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

With this you will have an at least 100% height containers that will grow if there is more content inside. But you can't use `height: 100%` for the child containers, but since usually the use case will be to have a container with a height equal to a screen percentage, you can use `vh` (viewport height units) to achieve this without worries about the height of the parent containers. You can create a class like this:

```
.full-height{
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use min-height for html and content instead of height attribute,

```
<style>
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body,
html {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.header,
.footer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Just remove `height:100%`.

```
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;<------Remove This----------
}
```

**Full Code :**

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body, html {
   height: 100%;
}

.header, .footer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Heading</h1>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>Sapibulumnibh phasellus nulla egestibulum enim pretium elit tincidunt estiquam ultrisque donectetur. Sedcondimentumsan odio hendrerit proin vitae dignis nibh ac justo id congue. Amesintesque vel curabitae volutpat donec alique nasceleifendimentesque
    montesque rhoncus quis eros. Vestnunc nonummy</p>

  <span>
                Sapibulumnibh phasellus nulla egestibulum enim pretium elit tincidunt estiquam ultrisque donectetur. Sedcondimentumsan odio hendrerit proin vitae dignis nibh ac justo id congue. Amesintesque vel curabitae volutpat donec alique nasceleifendimentesque montesque rhoncus quis eros. Vestnunc nonummy
            </span>
  <p>Sapibulumnibh phasellus nulla egestibulum enim pretium elit tincidunt estiquam ultrisque donectetur. Sedcondimentumsan odio hendrerit proin vitae dignis nibh ac justo id congue. Amesintesque vel curabitae volutpat donec alique nasceleifendimentesque
    montesque rhoncus quis eros. Vestnunc nonummy</p>

  <span>
                Sapibulumnibh phasellus nulla egestibulum enim pretium elit tincidunt estiquam ultrisque donectetur. Sedcondimentumsan odio hendrerit proin vitae dignis nibh ac justo id congue. Amesintesque vel curabitae volutpat donec alique nasceleifendimentesque montesque rhoncus quis eros. Vestnunc nonummy
            </span>
  <p>Sapibulumnibh phasellus nulla egestibulum enim pretium elit tincidunt estiquam ultrisque donectetur. Sedcondimentumsan odio hendrerit proin vitae dignis nibh ac justo id congue. Amesintesque vel curabitae volutpat donec alique nasceleifendimentesque
    montesque rhoncus quis eros. Vestnunc nonummy</p>

  <span>
                Sapibulumnibh phasellus nulla egestibulum enim pretium elit tincidunt estiquam ultrisque donectetur. Sedcondimentumsan odio hendrerit proin vitae dignis nibh ac justo id congue. Amesintesque vel curabitae volutpat donec alique nasceleifendimentesque montesque rhoncus quis eros. Vestnunc nonummy
            </span>
  <p>Sapibulumnibh phasellus nulla egestibulum enim pretium elit tincidunt estiquam ultrisque donectetur. Sedcondimentumsan odio hendrerit proin vitae dignis nibh ac justo id congue. Amesintesque vel curabitae volutpat donec alique nasceleifendimentesque
    montesque rhoncus quis eros. Vestnunc nonummy</p>

  <span>
                Sapibulumnibh phasellus nulla egestibulum enim pretium elit tincidunt estiquam ultrisque donectetur. Sedcondimentumsan odio hendrerit proin vitae dignis nibh ac justo id congue. Amesintesque vel curabitae volutpat donec alique nasceleifendimentesque montesque rhoncus quis eros. Vestnunc nonummy
            </span>
  <p>Sapibulumnibh phasellus nulla egestibulum enim pretium elit tincidunt estiquam ultrisque donectetur. Sedcondimentumsan odio hendrerit proin vitae dignis nibh ac justo id congue. Amesintesque vel curabitae volutpat donec alique nasceleifendimentesque
    montesque rhoncus quis eros. Vestnunc nonummy</p>

  <span>
                Sapibulumnibh phasellus nulla egestibulum enim pretium elit tincidunt estiquam ultrisque donectetur. Sedcondimentumsan odio hendrerit proin vitae dignis nibh ac justo id congue. Amesintesque vel curabitae volutpat donec alique nasceleifendimentesque montesque rhoncus quis eros. Vestnunc nonummy
            </span>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <h1>Footer
    <h1>
</div>
```